# Multiple WFEs conflicts with a sitecollection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection, front-end

Just a qucik one, what could be the possible cause of error, or where to look for fixing this error.

We got multiple front-ends, and everything is working fine. BUT, on the third WFE users cannot access a sitecollection Y. This sitecollection Y, can be accessed from all the other WFEs, and on the failing WFE users can acccess all other sitecollections besides sitecollection Y.

My logic is not enough to solve this.

Comment: Are you using alternate access mappings? Using a load balancer for the wfe's?

Comment: Yes, there is a LB and there is also AAM. The odd thing is that everything else can be accessed through the WFE except for this one sitecollection. I tried a iisreset on the Wfe, but that didnt help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that your AAM settings are correct. Then, add the third wfe as an "Internal URL" in AAM.

Also, verify that the hosts files on your all wfe's are correct. Test further, by adding/removing references to that troublesome wfe.

Have you checked out [this post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/aec37c8b-e724-45b0-8d26-aed7a6bae0b0/new-web-front-end-added-to-sp-2010-farm-sites-appear-fine-however-site-collections-do-not?forum=sharepointadminprevious)? It may also be helpful.

If that doesn't resolve your problem, browse to the offending site collection on wfe #3 and see what happens in the IIS logs. Post your findings as a reply to this answer and I'll dig in further.

Comment: Hey, Phil, i was away for a while. We tried AAM but it was already set up correctly. The IIS logs gave some errors, but we decided to remove the WFE from the environment, will maybe try to create it again on a sooner time, and do the configuraton again. Thanks for your advices. /emo

Comment: Review [this post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/a424307d-27d8-45ad-b160-2287b634f268/how-to-add-the-web-front-end-server-to-sharepoint-2010) and links contained within before you try adding the wfe again. Hope it works better next time!